# Dataset for Power Transmission Lines in Simulink, MATLAB

Tags: matlab, simulink

For power transmission lines faults dataset generation, I simulated a transmission line model in Simulink. I used three-phase fault component to generate different types of faults. The waveforms on the scope traced correctly but I want such data to be exported to MATLAB workspace for proper labelling. Can anyone suggest me, how can I generate the fault dataset?

V-I Measurements in Simulink

[image: V-I Measurements in Simulink]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I am unable to post a comment due to the lack of reputation, so I have to write an answer instead. Did you try to use `out_simout` in Simulink?

Here is the documentation too:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/toworkspace.html

You can check out this as well:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/export-simulation-data-1.html

Comment: Thank your for the information and is really helpful for me. Also it brought Simulink Block features into my notice which were overlooked by me.